# PyTest for DataPipelines

Tags: python, pytest, data-pipeline

My project is based on collecting infrastructure metrics like CPU, Memory, Disk, Hits for various servers and applications etc via Splunk RestAPI, HTTP API calls and shell scripts.
The python code written is procedural in nature.

I need to implement pytest for my project's python scripts.
Given the background of the project, our data loads are very dynamic and we are unable to figure out how to implement test cases for them as assertions will keep changing.

Can someone pls guide us if its possible to write test cases for such scripts.
If yes, how do we approach it.

Appreciate any inputs provided.

Thanks
Yavnica